# Django logging with several settings files

Tags: python, django, logging, django-settings

I'm having two problems with Django logging. I have this 3-tier project structure layout that I have written further down.

My two problems are:

1) I want only one unique logger for every app which writes to console. The only way of achieving this right now is adding app by app, as I'm doing right now. (I thought I would get this to work with the 'root' logger I modified. You can see the line in the settings file)

2) When coming to log **inside** one settings file, the console shows this warning:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "sonata.settings.local"
```

I'd like to be able to log at my settings files.

**project structure layout**

```
.
├── docs
├── requirements
├── scripts
└── sonata
    ├── person
    │   └── templatetags
    ├── registration
    ├── sonata
    │   └── settings
    │       ├── base.py
    │       ├── heroku.py
    │       ├── local.py
    |       └── production.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── css
    │   │   └── images
    │   ├── fonts
    │   └── js
    ├── templates
    │   ├── personApp
    │   └── registrationApp
    └── utils
        └── templatetags
```

---

**logging at base.py (main settings file)**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        '' : {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'sonata.settings.heroku' : {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'registration' : {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'level':'DEBUG',
        },
        'person' : {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'level':'DEBUG',
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'INFO'
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your logging configuration to be active, your settings have to be loaded. If you log in your settings file (or a module that is imported by it), your logging configuration is not yet loaded.

Have a look at [`django/__init__.py`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/8047e3666b0b50bb04e6f16c2a4fb21ddfd5713f/django/__init__.py):

```
...
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.log import configure_logging
...
```

The statement `LOGGING = ...` in your settings file doesn't actually configure the logging system. The configuration of the logging happens after the settings have been loaded.

You could configure logging manually in your settings file by directly using the `logging` module, but I would suggest you first evaluate if you *really* need to log in your settings file.

Comment: But my local.py "inherits" (not sure if it is the right word) from base.py all the logging (it has a "from base import *") and the     logging.getLogger(__name__)        is after that.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. Please see my edit for further explanation

Comment: Ok. I understand now. (2) is clear, Is there any solution for (1)?

Comment: Have you tried setting your `root` logger to log level `DEBUG`? Your `root` logger has log level `INFO`, your individual loggers have log level `DEBUG`.

Comment: I found that setting a logger with an empty string as a key ('') seems to work.